# What is the condition on $ \alpha $ to have polynomial solutions of : $ (\alpha + 2X)P - (X + 1)(X -3)P' = 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $P \text{ is a solution of the differential equation:} $
> $$\space (\alpha + 2X)P - (X + 1)(X -3)P' = 0 $$
> Solve the differential equation, and find the condition on $\alpha$ to have a polynomial solution.

---

Solving the differential equation, we have for $ x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1, 3\} $:

$$ \frac{P'(x)}{P(x)} = \frac{\alpha + 2x}{(x + 1)(x - 3)} = -\frac{\alpha + 2x}{4(x + 1)} + \frac{\alpha + 2x}{4(x - 3)} $$

Computing the antiderivatives, I found:

$$\begin{align}
& \implies \ln(|P(x)|) + C_1 = \ln|x + 1|^{-(\frac{\alpha}{4} + \frac{1}{2})}|x - 3|^{\frac{\alpha}{4} + \frac{3}{2}} + C_2 \\
& \implies P(x) = C|x + 1|^{-(\frac{\alpha}{4} + \frac{1}{2})}|x - 3|^{\frac{\alpha}{4} + \frac{3}{2}}
\end{align}$$

With: $C = e^{C_2 - C_1}$

For the solutions to be polynomial we need to have:
$ \frac{\alpha}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \leq 0 \text{   and   } \frac{\alpha}{4} + \frac{3}{2} \geq 0 \iff -6 \leq \alpha \leq -2 $

Although, $\alpha$ is an integer, when we test the numbers from $-6$ to $-2$, we found that the only values of $\alpha$ that give a polynomial solution are $-2$ and $-6$.

Others found different results than mine, was this correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake in writing the partial fractions. It should be

$$\frac{\alpha +2 x}{(x+1) (x-3)} = \frac{2-\alpha }{4 (x+1)}+\frac{\alpha +6}{4 (x-3)}$$

Using this to integrate you get
$$P(x) = C |1+x|^{\frac{2-\alpha}{4}} |x-3|^{\frac{\alpha+6}{4}}$$

Using your argument, this gives the range for $\alpha$ to $ \alpha \in [-6,2]$. Therefore, the solution set is $\{-6,-2,2 \}$

Comment: Thank you, answer accepted.